# OpenGL: How do you create a colormap texture?

Tags: opengl, textures, colormap

colorMap instantiation:

```
GLfloat colormapColors[16];
```

here's my colormap data:

```
colormapColors[0] =  0.0f; // black
colormapColors[1] =  0.0f;
colormapColors[2] =  0.0f;
colormapColors[3] =  0.0f;

colormapColors[4] =  0.0f; // blue
colormapColors[5] =  0.0f;
colormapColors[6] =  1.0f;
colormapColors[7] =  0.0f;

colormapColors[8] =  1.0f; // red
colormapColors[9] =  0.0f;
colormapColors[10] = 0.0f;
colormapColors[11] = 0.0f;

colormapColors[12] = 1.0f; // white
colormapColors[13] = 1.0f;
colormapColors[14] = 1.0f;
colormapColors[15] = 1.0f;
```

in my render loop I have

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture); // get texture id
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, texture);
glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, 4, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, colormapColors);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // linear interpolation when too small
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // linear interpolation when too bi
glErrorCheck;
```

fragment shader:

```
vec4 color = texture(ourTexture, clamp(alpha,0.0,1.0));
gl_FragColor = vec4(color.r, color.g, color.b, 1.0);
```

alpha is calculated by distance to center, and I get:

[image: bad dot]

so, clearly we have the black, blue, red, white. There should be no grey. I think it's a data alignment problem. Am I doing glTexImage1D wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)` so the edge texels won't be mixed with the ones on the other side.

You could also clamp the alpha value at the texel center (`[1/texSize;1-1/texSize]`), just to demonstrate how texel interpolation works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added gltexparameteri like you said and it got me closer to the right results, but it's not completely working. How do you clamp the alpha value at the texel center? Where do I apply this? `[1/texSize;1-1/texSize]`

Comment: How is it 'not completely working'? Please give more details.

Comment: My alpha channel was 1.0, so there was no blending going on when I would draw many circles.

Comment: Did you use `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` and `glBlendFunc()`?